# "example.com" forwards to "www.example.com", but "example.com/file.pdf" just forwards to "www.example.com". How to fix?

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, domain-forwarding, namecheap

*I don't know <strike>much</strike> anything about how hosting works, so if there's any additional info I should provide, please let me know.*

The URL `example.com` correctly forwards to `www.example.com`. But `example.com/file.pdf` and `example.com/some-blog-post` *also* forwards to `www.example.com` rather than `www.example.com/file.pdf` and `www.example.com/some-blog-post` as I'd like them to.

How can I set this up properly?

I'm hosting my personal website on GitHub pages, with a custom domain name through Namecheap. My current set up is the following:

```
Host Name   IP Address / URL        Record Type
@           http://www.example.com  URL Redirect
www         example.github.io       CNAME (Alias)
```

And the GitHub repository "`example.github.io`" contains a `CNAME` file at the top level that just contains the text

```
www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented this redirect with Namecheap.    [Their help document](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-url-forwarding-for-a-domain) explains how to set up the redirects either way:

> ```
> www1  http://destination.com      Permanent (301)
> www2  http://destination.com/     Permanent (301)
> ```
>
> In the above case, `www1.yourdomain.com` will not pass values to the destination URL so, `www1.yourdomain.com/xyz.html` will redirect users to `http://destination.com` only.
>
> On the otherhand, `www2.yourdomain.com/xyz.html` will redirect users to `http://destination.com/xyz.html` (pay attention to the `/` in the configuration).

So in Namecheap's interface, you need to ensure that your redirect rules have a trailing slash on the destination.

Comment: I missed that point in the docs. I even got on tech support with them, and it was never mentioned by the agent who helped me! I'll try it when I get home and update with results.

Comment: Changing `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/`  worked! It's in the details...

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is make `example.com` and `www.example.com` as separate URLs pointing to two different folders on the server, but make `www.example.com` point to the folder with the website contents.

Then these lines can be added to apache's main configuration file (*httpd.conf*) if you have `mod_rewrite` installed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Just make sure they are added before custom RewriteRule lines are processed for the `example.com` website if any.

Comment: Apparently GitHub pages won't allow this kind of thing: https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/, and the Jekyll gem only seems to work for subfolders, not subdomains: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from. Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you need to know type of content. redirection is perfect.
If you are redirecting based on server config(Apache), it is perfect.
`example.com/file.pdf` deposit as file and its source is `example.com`
so `example.com` redirect to `www.example.com` as deposit content as pdf

Upto this level,it is working fine.